# how can I access actionsheet buttons index number from another method?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

how can I access actionsheet buttons index number from another method? I want to set these index number to method parameter

Answer (score 0):

Use this delagate -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

you will get the buttonindex in this delegate and you can call another method from here.

Comment: I know the buttonIndex keep the index numbers but how can I pass this selected index to a web service?

Answer (score 0):

You have to impelement delegate method for action sheet,

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

In this you can  check for buttonIndex i.e. 0,1,2.. and do you want on selected index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method

```
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

to get the buttonIndex, and then call the method that connects to your webservice from there, passing in the buttonIndex as a parameter.  For instance:

```
- (void)methodThatCallsWebservice:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // however you call the webservice goes here
}


-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    [self methodThatCallWebservice:buttonIndex];
}
```